# Lots of RAM use by very large byte arrays?

Tags: android, arrays, memory, byte, ram

I have been trying to fix a memory leak in my app for a long time, and I keep running into dead ends. The app is heavily image-centric, so I use the Picasso library to handle caching and memory use. I passed the high ram use (up to 100-170mb for my app) to bad memory management on Picasso's part, but I did some testing and disabled memory caching for Picasso, which loads all my images, and there was not a very noticable drop in RAM usage. It was still using 90 to upwards of 170 mb of RAM. I did a full heap dump into a hprof file and opened it with MemoryAnalyzer to see this: 
http://i.gyazo.com/6b8d884852fa7cae546fc4cad1fc44c9.png.

If I go to Path to GC Roots, it shows no roots and no parents. There is no link to any of these over 50,000,000 bytes in these 25 massive byte arrays, and I really don't know where to start looking for the cause of it.
Do you have any suggestions on what the bug could be and any possible fixes?

Thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: Java is a garbage-collected language.  You may not recover that memory until some other application exerts memory pressure, and then the memory will be used by the other application, not freed.  In other words, it might not be a memory leak.

Comment: Although it might not be a leak, my app is still using 100-170 mb of RAM, and it causes many OOMs

Comment: Use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to see if you do have a leak.

Comment: @Emmanuel installed and using LeakCanary and nothing has been found. I have run into 2 OOMS already but nothing was reported, so I assume my issue is not memory leak related but rather a misuse of memory. My question still holds though!

Comment: @ccrama : how did you fix your issue .. I am also facing same problem .. I used LeakCanary ..nothign has been found!! could you please suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503505/reducing-high-consumption-of-ram-by-my-android-app

Comment: @NibhaJain to be honest, rewrote major parts of the app using better memory handling techniques, UniversalImageLoader, and good RecyclerView recycling practices.  My DisplayImageOptions for UIL looked like this:

new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
           .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
                .cacheInMemory(false)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(250))
                .build();

Comment: Thanks @ccrama I will see what can I do in my case..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`LeakCanary`](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to find the memory leak.

Also, you can try [`Fresco`](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) for image loading & displaying, it stores images in the native memory region, so you won't use too much memory from the managed region, GC won't take too much time and you could avoid `OutOfMemoryError`s.

Comment: Hadn't heard of Fresco, trying that out now! Also I found a few bugs with LeakCanary (unrelated), so thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately Fresco bumped my memory use up about 30 MB switching from Picasso. This leads me to believe bitmaps are NOT the issue, and there is some other underlying problem with a library or my code. The main memory killer is the nine million long byte array full of just -1's.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken. Fresco got me down to about 90mb which is ~ a 10-20 mb drop in RAM usage. The image part is fixed, but the byte array issue still persists.